# change value after intent is started

Tags: android, android-intent

In the onStart of my activity I put this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, CLPayPalService.config);
startService(intent);
```

where CLPayPalService.config is this:

```
public static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(BuildTypeConfiguration.CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(BuildTypeConfiguration.CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
        .acceptCreditCards(VAR);
```

Now after the activity is started the users get the possibility to set there country. And after that is set, I would like to change the value of VAR.

But the intent is already started. How can I change that value? Because just setting the VAR again doesn't work. The intent works with the first setting of var only.

Is there a way to change this? I can't get into the started intent because that is from paypal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an Intent has been handed to the system there is no way of changing it's values. The only solution is to change the value and re-start the service.

Comment: If I do this what happens with the old intent? Because I don't know how paypal is doing this behind the scenes. Does paypal use the old intent or the new one?

Comment: That might change with different implementations. In order to be safe, make sure to gather all values before you fire your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I set the value afterwards and then start the intent. It is not necessary to start the intent in the onStart.